# How to install CartoDB driver for ogr2ogr?

Tags: carto, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to import data from my postgis DB directly into CartoDB. I've seen in [this forum's post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152330/importing-data-to-cartodb-using-ogr2ogr/152339#152339?newreg=b4127807ff014b768399ca76d589c037) that I can do that with ogr2ogr, a GDAL tool, in this way:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 --config CARTODB_API_KEY XXXX -f CartoDB 
"CartoDB:account" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres
dbname=cartodb_dev_user port=5432" "public.table_name"
```

However, when I try, I get this error message:

```
Unable to find driver `CartoDB'.
```

I don't have the driver for CartoDB installed, but I'm not sure how to install it. I see there's [this help site](http://www.gdal.org/drv_cartodb.html), but it doesn't mention how to install it.

My current version of GDAL is 1.10.1 and I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Comment: Read the first line of the document page "(GDAL/OGR >= 1.11)". You can't get CartoDB into 1.10.