# Error trying to import data to CartoDB using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, carto, ogr2ogr

I have a local install of CartoDB in my Ubuntu 14.04. I have created a CartoDB account called "development" and been playing with it for a while. Now I'd like to import some data from a shapefile directly using ogr2ogr.

I've installed GDAL 2.0 since [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152330/importing-data-to-cartodb-using-ogr2ogr) mentioned ogr2ogr wouldn't create new tables in CartoDB unless upgraded to 2.0, and tried this command:

```
ogr2ogr --config CARTODB_API_KEY XXXX -f CartoDB "CartoDB:development" myfile.shp
```

This is what I get:

```
ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 404
ERROR 1: HTML error page returned by server
ERROR 1: CartoDB driver doesn't support database creation.
CartoDB driver failed to create CartoDB:development
```

Comment: Having this error too... does it mean you have to have the table created first in CartoDB then you can run GDAL to populate it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have the ogr2ogr syntax wrong. The last line suggests that ogr2ogr didn't expect that type of argument.

I'm using GDAL 2.1.0dev, and this works for me:

`ogr2ogr --config CARTODB_API_KEY XXXX -f CartoDB CartoDB:wri-02 myfile.shp`

I think you just need to remove the quotes around the `"CartoDB:Development"`, provided that your account is really development.cartodb.com.